# Cannot get value by GET method in php after modifying .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to .htaccess, I have the following problem.

this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

I have the link below. If the path is like this, I can get the `type` variable with `$_GET['type']`

```
http://myurl/mypage&type=example
```

but if it is like this then I cannot get a `type` value equal to `$_GET['type']`

```
http://myurl/mypage?type=example
```

the difference on the url is `?type` and `&type`.
So how do I edit my .htaccess file to get the value at the second url?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[QSA]` after the rewrite rule to append the original query string to the new url:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa